# Problem with User input to .bat script

Tags: scripting, batch-file, cmd

I wrote the following .bat script

```
@echo off
@rem set variables
set CURRENT_DIR=%cd%
set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0%
set Program Files=%Program Files:Program Files=Progra~1%

:input
set INPUT=
echo Following are the installation choices you have:
echo        1. Choice1
echo        2. Choice2
echo        3. Choice3

set /P INPUT=Please select any of the above choice (1to 3) : %=%
echo input is %INPUT%
if "%INPUT%"=="" goto input

if "%INPUT%"=="1" (
    echo Choice 1 selected
    goto QUITNOW
)

if "%INPUT%"=="2" (
echo Choice 2 selected
set /p INPUT_1=Please enter input 1: %=%
echo input_1 is  %INPUT_1%
goto QUITNOW
)

if "%INPUT%"=="3" (
echo Choice 3 selected
set /p input_3= Please enter input_3: %=%
echo %input_3%
)

:QUITNOW
cd %CURRENT_DIR%
@echo on
```

At first when it ask me to select the choice and i entered 2,it set the INPUT variable to 2 and it goes in second if block. In if block again it ask for the input (INPUT_1),i do enter the input word but looks like this time its not setting the INPUT_1 variable.Do anyone have any idea where am i doing wrong. Following the the output of the script with my inputs

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>scriptA.bat
Following are the installation choices you have:
        1. Choice1
        2. Choice2
        3. Choice3
Please select any of the above choice (1to 3) : 2
input is 2
Choice 2 selected
Please enter input 1: failingHere
input_1 is

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>
```

So if you observe its not printing the "failingHere" input. Please help and let me know if you need any further information regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
if "%INPUT%"=="2" (
    echo Choice 2 selected
    set /p INPUT_1=Please enter input 1: %=%
    echo input_1 is  %INPUT_1%
    goto QUITNOW
)
```

This *entire* block is evaluated (for environment variables) before *any* of it is run. That means `%INPUT_1%` is evaluated before being set.

What you need to do is put:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the top of your script (and `endlocal` before exiting) and use the delayed expansion symbols thus:

```
if "%INPUT%"=="2" (
    echo Choice 2 selected
    set /p INPUT_1=Please enter input 1: %=%
    echo input_1 is  !INPUT_1!
    goto QUITNOW
)
```

You can see this in action with the following script:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set xx=1
if %xx%==1 (
    set xx=2
    echo %xx%
    echo !xx!
)
endlocal
```

which outputs:

```
1
2
```

because `%xx%` is evaluated at the time the entire `if` *statement* is read while `!xx!` is evaluated when that *line* is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You used the ms-dos/dos-batch tags, but I don't think set /p is already available in MS-DOS. I thought it to be added to the Windows command prompt (cmd). 
If not, it would have made my batch-based text adventure a lot easier if I had known it back then. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using /p and not /P. Change that and will works.

```
if "%INPUT%"=="2" (
echo Choice 2 selected
set /P INPUT_1=Please enter input 1: %=%
echo input_1 is  %INPUT_1%
goto QUITNOW
)
```

Comment: I tried that but its same. Just FYI i am running this from cmd,but i hope that won't cause be an issue.

Comment: You're right. That is not the problem, sorry. Paxdiablo are right.